# Wordpress $wpdb->prepare() put slashes in the inserted values?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, escaping

I just noticed that `$wpdb->prepare()` put slashes in the inserted values while it shouldn't cause this! e.g.: if you insert 'test' as a value it ends up as \'test\' in its table field.

How can I reliably remove those slashes when retrieving data from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It escapes some special characters before storing them on your data base. You can use function **stripslashes** on your data after reading, to restore it.